# Extracting a number in Java isn't working as expected

Tags: java, loops, console, numbers, number-formatting

This program is supposed to print the numbers (indiviual digits) in a number
`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    int Size = 0;
    String Conversion = Integer.toString(number);
    Size = Conversion.length();
    int n = 0;
    while (n <= Size){
      int d = number%10;
      int power = Size - 2;
      number = (number/(10^(power)));
      System.out.println(d);
      n += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

`

Really Appreciate for Anyone for Took time to help me.
Thanks

For some reason I get
1
9
3.

instead of
1
3
4

using the debugger gives me some hint, Specifically this block `

```
number = (number/(10^(power)));
```

`

for second iteration the value is +4 than expected, 3.

for third Its okay.
changing and adding +4 on that block gives
1
3
7
4

Comment: `10^(power)` <- I'd recommend reading up what the `^` operator actually does instead of just assuming it is used to calculate powers of numbers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: You shouldn't use either. Just divide by 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot OH GOD SPIDERS and tkausl. Got it working. Using a Carrot character does NOT help. Anyways I wanted to extract digits from a unknown number with unknown digit. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 2):

Found it !!
Credit OH GOD SPIDERS, tkausl

Solution 1 : Instead of using carrot characters in

```
number = (number/(10^(power)));
```

use Math.pow function.

Solution 2 :

Don't use (number/(10^(power))
instead just divide by 10

Comment: Solution 3: You've already converted the number to a string `Conversion`, just access the digits via the `substring()` method or `charAt()` or any number of methods.